# How to parse a Chart using data from a nested object in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js, javascript-objects

I am trying to parse a piechart out of an json-object which I get by calling an API. I want to use a specific key-value pair for rendering of the piechart itself.

I then want to use some other key-value results in my tooltips.

Imagine the following scenario which works so far.

```
const labels = [
'Januar',
'Februar'
];

const data = {
labels: labels,
datasets: [{
label: 'My First dataset',
backgroundColor: ["#0074D9", "#FF4136"],
data: [req('url').current_price.eur, req('url').current_price.eur],
}]
```

```
const config = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
plugins: {
  tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    usePointStyle: true,
    callbacks: { 
      title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        console.log(tooltipItem);
        return "Index " + tooltipItem[0].label;
              },

      label: (context) => { 
              console.log('context', context);
                return 'test'
              
      }
    },
  },
},
},
};

const myChart = new Chart(
document.getElementById('myChart'),
config
);

<html>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

      <div>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
       
</html>
```

So what I'm trying, is calling the API in `data` without the keys, so that I can access the object in `context` and use some of this values in my label for example.

I found the

```
parsing: {
                yAxisKey: 'current_price.eur'
            }
```

config but this isn't working for me if I change everything according to my idea, so that it renders the `current_price.eur` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pie/doughnut charts you need to specify the `key` option since it doesnt use any axes. So if you make your object like (together with latest version, 3.6.0) this it should work:

```js
parsing: {
  key: 'current_price.eur'
}
```

Example of object pie chart:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [{
          id: 'parent1',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'parent2',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'paren3',
          key: 30
        }],
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
          id: 'child1',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'child2',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'child3',
          key: 30
        }, {
          id: 'child4',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'child5',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'child6',
          key: 30
        }],
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (ttItem) => (`${ttItem.raw.id}: ${ttItem.raw.key}`)
        }
      }
    },
    parsing: {
      key: 'key'
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect that works for me. If you want you can provide my workaround as well. The `const data` can be accessed with `context` in the tooltips so if someone adds an object like `apiData: apiData` there it can be accessed and used.